# how to change position of title, text and dot indicator to bottom left in all slides

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i got this intro tutorial from the flutter website and i am trying to create a welcome screen but i would like to position the title on the bottom left of the screen and the description underneath it once again towards the left and under that have the dot indicator.
Is there a way to add a position argument or allignment?

```
class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  IntroScreenState createState() => IntroScreenState();
}

class IntroScreenState extends State<IntroScreen> {
  List<Slide> slides = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Tailored For You",
        maxLineTitle: 2,
        styleTitle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        description:
            "lorem ipsum dolore",
        styleDescription: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF8F8F8F),
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        marginDescription:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 70.0),
        // centerWidget: Text("Replace this with a custom widget",
        //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundImage:
            "/Users/demis/Desktop/club_rat/club_rat/lib/assets/images/bg1.jpg",
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topLeft,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomRight,
        onCenterItemPress: () {},
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "CITY",
        styleTitle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        description: "lorem ipsum",
        styleDescription: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF8F8F8F),
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        backgroundImage: "images/city.jpeg",
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topRight,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "BEACH",
        styleTitle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        description: "lorem ipsum",
        styleDescription: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF8F8F8F),
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        backgroundImage: "images/beach.jpeg",
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
  }

  void onDonePress() {
    // Do what you want
    // Navigator.push(
    //   context,
    //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
    // );
  }

  Widget renderNextBtn() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.navigate_next,
      color: Color(0xffF3B4BA),
      size: 35.0,
    );
  }

  Widget renderDoneBtn() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.done,
      color: Color(0xffF3B4BA),
    );
  }

  Widget renderSkipBtn() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.skip_next,
      color: Color(0xffF3B4BA),
    );
  }

  ButtonStyle myButtonStyle() {
    return ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(StadiumBorder()),
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0x33F3B4BA)),
      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0x33FFA8B0)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new IntroSlider(
      // List slides
      slides: this.slides,

      // Skip button
      renderSkipBtn: this.renderSkipBtn(),
      skipButtonStyle: myButtonStyle(),

      // Next button
      renderNextBtn: this.renderNextBtn(),
      nextButtonStyle: myButtonStyle(),

      // Done button
      renderDoneBtn: this.renderDoneBtn(),
      onDonePress: this.onDonePress,
      doneButtonStyle: myButtonStyle(),

      // Dot indicator
      colorDot: Color(0x33FFA8B0),
      colorActiveDot: Color(0xffFFA8B0),
      sizeDot: 13.0,

      // Show or hide status bar
      hideStatusBar: true,
      backgroundColorAllSlides: Colors.grey,

      // Scrollbar
      verticalScrollbarBehavior: scrollbarBehavior.SHOW_ALWAYS,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please wrap `IntroSlider` with the `Align` widget inside `Scaffold` and then pass `alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft`. It will align `IntroSlider` to the bottom left of the screen.

Comment: The change did not work. Nothing changed and both the title and description are still at the top slider position also remained unchanged

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check now.